# Java - Initialize array in constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I want to initialize two dimensional array in constructor. But, I have a problem when I declare instance variable of array in class. It will be error if I make it like this:

```
public class Data {
private String [][] tabel;
public Data(){
    tabel = {{"ID", "NAME"},
             {"101", "Max"},
             {"102", "Mark"},
             {"103", "Downey"},
             {"104", "Matthew"},
             {"105", "Richard"}};
}
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: add new String[] before each {} block

Comment: If you don't do it on the same line as the declaration, you need to use `new`.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write `new Type[]` in front of the array initializers like so:

```
tabel = new String[][]{
            new String[]{"ID", "NAME"},
            new String[]{"101", "Max"},
            new String[]{"102", "Mark"},
            new String[]{"103", "Downey"},
            new String[]{"104", "Matthew"},
            new String[]{"105", "Richard"}};
```